# How to install and call package ‘multidplyr’ using windows 10 and R 3.4.4

Tags: r, github, multidplyr

I have attempted to use 
  `devtools::install_github("hadley/multidplyr")`

however when I use it I get the error

```
 Error: Failed to install 'multidplyr' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
```

Comment: Did you already have the `rlang` package loaded when you tried to install the package? Restart your R session and try before loading any other packages.

Comment: I installed dependency 'qs' manually and reinstalled 'rlang' then 'multidplyr' ran successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed dependency 'qs' manually and reinstalled 'rlang' then 'multidplyr' ran successfully

install.packages ('qs')
install.packages ('rlang')